# Checking every digit in a variable to an array using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Backstory: I'm creating a code-guessing game. The user must enter 4 digits which will be compared to the actual code. Program outputs amount of digits guessed correctly in the correct place and how many correct digits in the wrong place. The array varr changes to False when a digit in the guess is correctly matched with a digit in the code.

```
 varr= [code(0), code(1), code(2), code(3)]
```

For this I need to create two for loops. "For each digit in guess that does match to the code..." and "For remaining digits in the array"

How do I write this in Python?

Comment: Do you have restrict that all the digits are different?

Comment: The digits in code are random. The digits of guess can be the same but shouldn't be compared to each other more than once

Comment: Can you show a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignore the codes of generating the list and user input part, just to show the core codes:

```
from collections import Counter


def main():
    answers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    guesses = [3, 5, 6, 4]

    answers_counter = Counter(answers)
    guesses_counter = Counter(guesses)
    diff_counter = answers_counter - guesses_counter
    number_of_all_correct_digits = len(answers) - len(diff_counter.values())

    number_of_correct_digits_in_correct_place = len(
        list(filter(lambda x: x == 0, [a - g for a, g in zip(answers, guesses)])))

    number_of_correct_digits_in_wrong_place = number_of_all_correct_digits - number_of_correct_digits_in_correct_place

    return number_of_correct_digits_in_correct_place, number_of_correct_digits_in_wrong_place


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r1, r2 = main()
    print(r1)
    print(r2)
```

and it product the result, number of correct digits in the right place:1 (digit 3), number of correct digits in the wrong place: 1 (digit 4)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
import random

first_lock = random.randint(1, 50)
second_lock = random.randint(1, 50)
third_lock = random.randint(1, 50)
fourth_lock = random.randint(1, 50)

combination_dict = {
  'one': lambda one, cd, wd: (cd + 1, wd) if first_lock == one else (cd, wd + 1),
  'two': lambda two, cd, wd: (cd + 1, wd) if second_lock == two else (cd, wd + 1),
  'three': lambda three, cd, wd: (cd + 1, wd) if third_lock == three else (cd, wd + 1),
  'four':  lambda four, cd, wd: (cd + 1, wd) if fourth_lock == four else (cd, wd + 1)
}

def combination_lock(one, two, three, four):
  cd = 0
  wd = 0
  cd, wd = combination_dict['one'](one, cd, wd)
  cd, wd = combination_dict['two'](two, cd, wd)
  cd, wd = combination_dict['three'](three, cd, wd)
  cd, wd = combination_dict['four'](four, cd, wd)

  return cd, wd


def game_start():
  correct_digits = 0
  wrong_digits = 0

  locked = True
  while locked:
    correct_digits = 0
    wrong_digits = 0

    one = int(raw_input("First Lock: "))
    two = int(raw_input("Second Lock: "))
    three = int(raw_input("Third Lock: "))
    four = int(raw_input("Fourth Lock: "))

    correct_digits, wrong_digits = combination_lock(one, two, three, four)

    if (first_lock == one) and (second_lock == two) and (third_lock == three) and (fourth_lock == four):
      locked = False
      print "Congratz you escaped the locked room!"
    else:
      print "Right digits: ", str(correct_digits)
      print "Wrong digits: ", str(wrong_digits)

game_start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest** and most readable solution is not require couple of **for loops**

```
random_code = [2, 3, 4, 5]
user_code = [2, 5, 6, 7]
result = []
correct_guess = 0
correct_place = 0 
for i in xrange(4):
    if user_code[i] == random_code[i]:
        result.append(user_code[i])
        correct_place += 1
    else:
        result.append('X')
    if user_code[i] in random_code:
        correct_guess += 1
```

I've added `result` as visual representation. Your output:

```
>>> correct_guess
2
>>> correct_place
1
>>> result
[2, 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

By the way, you have to keep in mind the assumption that your player code will have the same length as your randomly generated code

It's very important because it might be the cause of a bug :D

FYI you can do

```
random_code.index(NUMBER)
```

If it won't be in the list you will get

```
ValueError: NUMBER is not in list
```

If NUMBER will be in the list you will get its position (0,1,2 or 3 in our case) so then you can compare positions of element in two lists.

Goodluck!

Comment: I've done something similar except it didn't work for the problem. Two loops are necessary to cancel out correct place and wrong place both being 4